# Get source line number from map file for a DLL

Tags: delphi, debugging, exception, stack

When an EXE raised an exception message like "access violation at address XXXXXXXX...", the address XXXXXXXX is a hex value, and we can get the source code line number that caused the exception,  by looking at the map file. Details below ([by madshi at EE](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_21201209.html#a12542996)):

> you need to substract the image base,
>   which is most probably $400000.
>   Furthermore you need to substract the
>   "base of code" address, which is
>   stored in the image nt headers of each
>   module (exe/dll). It's usually $1000.
>   You can check which value it has by
>   using the freeware tool "PEProwse
>   Pro". It's the field "Base Of Code" in
>   the "Details" of the "Optional
>   Header". You'll also find the image
>   base address there.

**My question is**: How to get the source line number for a **DLL**? Does the same calculation apply? Thanks!

Note 1: the map file is generated by Delphi and I'm not sure if this matters.

Note 2: I've been using JCL DEBUG but it couldn't catch the exception which seems occurred at the startup of the DLL (an Office add-in, actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same calculations apply, with the following note: instead of image base address of EXE you'll need to take actual address where DLL had been loaded. Base of code for a DLL should taken in the same manner as for EXE (stored in PE's `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`).

Btw, EXE and DLL are actually the same thing from the point of view of PE format.

Comment: I would like also to recommend a tool to simplify the task - if you deal with x64 - `dumpbin` is powerful enough. If you consider 32-bit images only - Total Commander has very convenient PEViewer plugin, which makes PE headers analysis quite an easy task.

Comment: This is indeed correct. Just make sure that the DLL hasn't been rebased as part of loading - you can do this using the `{$IMAGEBASE }` option, say in the .dpr file, and choosing a location which doesn't clash with other DLLs in your process.

Comment: Would be nice to need an x64 tool for a Delphi DLL, wouldn't it!

Comment: While debugging, the IDE shows the base address of loaded dlls in its "event log" (debugger options -> event log). If statically linked, the "modules" view has also this information.

Comment: The simplest way to find the actual address where DLL is loaded - SysInternals' `Process Explorer` is *the right tool* for that.

Comment: What's the easiest way to get the actual base address when the DLL is loaded? Since the Word addin is running on an end user's computer...

Answer (score 1):

Two binaries can not be loaded at the same address. So the image base address stored in the DLL/EXE is only a suggestion for which the binary is optimized. Where the binary actually gets loaded into memory depends on many factors, like other binaries loaded in the process first, Windows version, injected 3rd party dlls, etc.

As suggested you can use a debugger or a tool like Process Explorer to find out at what address the DLL is loaded at that time. Or if you want to know from code you can by getting the HInstance or HModule from the DLL [since both are the same](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/14/155107.aspx) and are the address in memory the DLL is loaded at. Delphi gets you the HModule for other DLL's through the GetModuleHandle method. Newer Delphi versions also have other methods to find HInstance.

Comment: In practice you can invariably use `$IMAGEBASE` to arrange that your DLL loads at its preferred address without the need for load time rebasing and it's wise to do this.

Comment: Determining a 'free' address can be difficult since it can change if any of your process' other dlls change in size or if some 3rd party application, like a screen capture program, injects dlls into your process etc.

Comment: Thanks Lars, any code example to convert hInstance to the 'base image' address? Thanks!